# Can't load library JNIConnector.dll

Tags: java-native-interface, call, skype

I want to test java api Skype, when i run it, I get those errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\FAC\AppData\Local\Temp\JNIConnector.dll
```

My class is :

```
import com.skype.Skype;
import com.skype.SkypeException;

public class SkypeMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String skypeUser="or.test";
    try {
        Skype.call(skypeUser).setReceiveVideoEnabled(true);
    } catch (SkypeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a file search for JNIConnector.dll and determine where it is.  If you can't find the file, then you'll need to add it to your path or classpath.

Are you using [Skype-Command](http://code.google.com/p/skype-command-line/downloads/detail?name=skype-command_1.2.zip&can=2&q=)?  if not you might want to check it out.

The JNIConnector.dll is in the lib directory here:

http://code.google.com/p/skype-command-line/source/browse/trunk/skypeCommand